# path to assets in flash builder

Tags: flash, flash-builder, embed

so in my main flash builder project I have a folder called assets. When I am embedding into a class I have to use the code.

[Embed(source="../../assets/ship.png")]

Is there away to add the assets folder to avoid the double folder traverse?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add additional source paths to your project so FB knows where to look for assets/code outside of the default src folder

To add folders:

goto FB menu -> Project -> Properties -> Flex Build Path

Select "Source Path" tab, click "Add Folder" and select your assets folder.

Then adjust your Embed paths to eg: [Embed(source="/ship.png")]

(I left the slash in place as FB seems to prefer it that way)

Comment: nice one, n. It was no big deal but just looks neater.